# Problems with publisher/printing

Tags: print-design, svg, shadows

I am not a professional, and I have not had any training - so please forgive me if I don't use the right terms.

I am designing some material for my work - designing in publisher. In the background I have an image, svg file, with (in my computer) a transparent background. When I finished the draft, saved as a pdf and sent it on to be edited. They printed and around the SVG image is a gray box. It isn't there on my pdf nor when I print. Is this a problem with the svg image or the person printing...and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: You should always request a hardcopy first. And you should allways check your PDF carefully. SVG is a terrible idea for print though. I wouldnt rule out error on your part. In either case the damage has been done. By the way this is one of the reasons pros use adobe apps. it saves them money on mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the damage is done. I did have a hard copy and in my hard copy there was no shadow. That is why I am confused.

Comment: SVG is **not** an appropriate file format for commercially printed artwork.

Answer (score 0):

When working in print you want to have anything that needs to have a transparent background be a straight vector element or a png.

What you are describing sounds like there might be some overprint or some background being saved into it when you make it a pdf.

Can you expand on what you are doing for us? Are you taking this svg and saving it as a pdf then putting that pdf into another document? How are you using this image?

Comment: That is exactly what I was wondering. If I change the svg to a png will that fix the problem?

Comment: I put the svg into publisher along with the text and the rest of the document. Then saved the whole thing as a pdf. Does that make sense?